# Indirect clustering / association finding

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, association-rules, latent-class

I'm looking for recommendations of techniques that allow me to cluster or find associated items, through an indirect layer.

Imagine a hypothetical database of information about patients, including what diseases they have, and what medications they are taking.  For example:

Pt. 1: {headache, high cholesterol, ibuprofen, simvastatin}
Pt. 2: {ear infection, high cholesterol, amoxicillin, simvastatin}
Pt. 3: {high cholesterol, atorvastatin}
Pt. 4: {diabetes, high cholesterol, metformin, atorvastatin}

Simvastatin and atorvastatin are both statins, and both treat high cholesterol.  However, they almost never co-occur in the same patient, because patients almost never take two statins.

I'd like to find a techinque that could infer that simvastatin and atorvastatin are similar to each other.  I've considered clustering and association rule mining but am not sure how to account for the indirect layer.  I could also try to use something like association rule mining to find that both medicines are associated with high cholesterol, and then conclude for myself that they must be related, but I'm curious if there's a technique that can handle this directly.

It would be a bonus if the method could take other variables (like patient sex or age) into account, in addition to their medications and diseases.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't take the approach you are suggesting, but rather would get the SMILES string for atorvastatin and perform a structure search for compounds similar to atorvastatin first, then build libraries.  Unless you have all the drug names you need to use, and have incorporated that into your search tool.  Going through patient data would be a distaster, especially when trying to learn via independent associations that two drugs are probably related only because they are seen for hypercholesterolemia patients.

However, you already know that all the statins are related by using the "truth table."   Like, "cars have engines." You approach would assume first that "cars have exhaust systems", and "auto exhaust systems are used for muffling noise from the engine," --> aha, therefore "cars also have engines."  However, the truth table rule before making this analogy states that "rule: cars have engines."  The same applies to statins before you do your learning analysis: the truth table states that "rule: rosuvastatin, simvastatin, atorvastatin,..., [list all statins here] are all statins which are used for lowering LDL."  Now, why are you doing your analysis to discover that simvastatin and atorvastatin are used for the same treatment.

If your goal is drug similarity, then just get atorvastatin's structure and perform a structure search at e.g. PubChem or Zinc15.  Otherwise, you want to use an analysis called "Association Rules" or "market basket analysis" which for example, sorts to the top of a list the most frequent item associations seen is all "shoppers baskets" at checkout.  Amazon, Walmart, everyone actually use association analysis for identify products purchased together, like "other books people have purchased" shown below when looking at a book on amazon.  You would have to make a list of drugs or whatever you are interested in to pull those words out of the results of association rule (market basket) analysis.  I have actually done this on patient data for people with DM to see what else they had in terms of race, gender, comorbidities, etc.